# Ошибка Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function at HTMLDocument - как решить?

Tags: javascript, opencart

Сайт находится на хостинге. Не работает переключатель валют. В консоли ошибки:

>

```
 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (VM1757 common.js:132)
    at j (VM1755 jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (VM1755 jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (VM1755 jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (VM1755 jquery.min.js:2)

common.js:132 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (VM1757 common.js:132)
    at j (VM1755 jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (VM1755 jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (VM1755 jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (VM1755 jquery.min.js:2)

common.js:132 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (VM1757 common.js:132)
    at j (VM1755 jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (VM1755 jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (VM1755 jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (VM1755 jquery.min.js:2)

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (VM1757 common.js:132)
    at j (VM1755 jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (VM1755 jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (VM1755 jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (VM1755 jquery.min.js:2)
common.js:132 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (common.js:132)
    at j (jquery.js:3148)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3260)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js:3472)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.js:3503)
```

common.js

```js
function getURLVar(key) {
 var value = [];

 var query = document.location.search.split('?');

 if (query[1]) {
  var part = query[1].split('&');

  for (i = 0; i < part.length; i++) {
   var data = part[i].split('=');

   if (data[0] && data[1]) {
    value[data[0]] = data[1];
   }
  }

  if (value[key]) {
   return value[key];
  } else {
   return '';
  }
 }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
 // Highlight any found errors
 $('.text-danger').each(function() {
  var element = $(this).parent().parent();

  if (element.hasClass('form-group')) {
   element.addClass('has-error');
  }
 });

 // Currency
 $('#form-currency a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $('#form-currency input[name=\'code\']').val($(this).attr('name'));

  $('#form-currency').submit();
 });

 // Language
 $('#form-language a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $('#form-language input[name=\'code\']').val($(this).attr('name'));

  $('#form-language').submit();
 });

 /* Search */
 $('#search input[name=\'search\']').parent().find('button').on('click', function() {
  var url = $('base').attr('href') + 'index.php?route=product/search';

  var value = $('header #search input[name=\'search\']').val();

  if (value) {
   url += '&search=' + encodeURIComponent(value);
  }

  location = url;
 });

 $('#search input[name=\'search\']').on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
   $('header #search input[name=\'search\']').parent().find('button').trigger('click');
  }
 });

 // Menu
 $('#menu .dropdown-menu').each(function() {
  var menu = $('#menu').offset();
  var dropdown = $(this).parent().offset();

  var i = (dropdown.left + $(this).outerWidth()) - (menu.left + $('#menu').outerWidth());

  if (i > 0) {
   $(this).css('margin-left', '-' + (i + 10) + 'px');
  }
 });

 // Product List
 $('#list-view').click(function() {
  $('#content .product-grid > .clearfix').remove();

  $('#content .row > .product-grid').attr('class', 'product-layout product-list col-xs-12');
  $('#grid-view').removeClass('active');
  $('#list-view').addClass('active');

  localStorage.setItem('display', 'list');
 });

 // Product Grid
 $('#grid-view').click(function() {
  // What a shame bootstrap does not take into account dynamically loaded columns
  var cols = $('#column-right, #column-left').length;

  if (cols == 2) {
   $('#content .product-list').attr('class', 'product-layout product-grid col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12');
  } else if (cols == 1) {
   $('#content .product-list').attr('class', 'product-layout product-grid col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12');
  } else {
   $('#content .product-list').attr('class', 'product-layout product-grid col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12');
  }

  $('#list-view').removeClass('active');
  $('#grid-view').addClass('active');

  localStorage.setItem('display', 'grid');
 });

 if (localStorage.getItem('display') == 'list') {
  $('#list-view').trigger('click');
  $('#list-view').addClass('active');
 } else {
  $('#grid-view').trigger('click');
  $('#grid-view').addClass('active');
 }

 // Checkout
 $(document).on('keydown', '#collapse-checkout-option input[name=\'email\'], #collapse-checkout-option input[name=\'password\']', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
   $('#collapse-checkout-option #button-login').trigger('click');
  }
 });

 // tooltips on hover
 $('[data-toggle=\'tooltip\']').tooltip({container: 'body',trigger: 'hover'});

 // Makes tooltips work on ajax generated content
 $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
  $('[data-toggle=\'tooltip\']').tooltip({container: 'body'});
 });
});

// Cart add remove functions
var cart = {
 'add': function(product_id, quantity) {
  $.ajax({
   url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
   type: 'post',
   data: 'product_id=' + product_id + '&quantity=' + (typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1),
   dataType: 'json',
   beforeSend: function() {
    $('#cart > button').button('loading');
   },
   complete: function() {
    $('#cart > button').button('reset');
   },
   success: function(json) {
    $('.alert, .text-danger').remove();

    if (json['redirect']) {
     location = json['redirect'];
    }

    if (json['success']) {
     $('#content').parent().before('<div class="alert alert-success"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> ' + json['success'] + ' <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');

     // Need to set timeout otherwise it wont update the total
     setTimeout(function () {
      $('#cart > button').html('<span id="cart-total"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> ' + json['total'] + '</span>');
     }, 100);

     $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');

     $('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
    }
   },
   error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
   }
  });
 },
 'update': function(key, quantity) {
  $.ajax({
   url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/edit',
   type: 'post',
   data: 'key=' + key + '&quantity=' + (typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1),
   dataType: 'json',
   beforeSend: function() {
    $('#cart > button').button('loading');
   },
   complete: function() {
    $('#cart > button').button('reset');
   },
   success: function(json) {
    // Need to set timeout otherwise it wont update the total
    setTimeout(function () {
     $('#cart > button').html('<span id="cart-total"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> ' + json['total'] + '</span>');
    }, 100);

    if (getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/cart' || getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/checkout') {
     location = 'index.php?route=checkout/cart';
    } else {
     $('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
    }
   },
   error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
   }
  });
 },
 'remove': function(key) {
  $.ajax({
   url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/remove',
   type: 'post',
   data: 'key=' + key,
   dataType: 'json',
   beforeSend: function() {
    $('#cart > button').button('loading');
   },
   complete: function() {
    $('#cart > button').button('reset');
   },
   success: function(json) {
    // Need to set timeout otherwise it wont update the total
    setTimeout(function () {
     $('#cart > button').html('<span id="cart-total"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> ' + json['total'] + '</span>');
    }, 100);
    
    var now_location = String(document.location.pathname);

    if ((now_location == '/cart/') || (now_location == '/checkout/') || (getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/cart') || (getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/checkout')) {
     location = 'index.php?route=checkout/cart';
    } else {
     $('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
    }
   },
   error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
   }
  });
 }
}

var voucher = {
 'add': function() {

 },
 'remove': function(key) {
  $.ajax({
   url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/remove',
   type: 'post',
   data: 'key=' + key,
   dataType: 'json',
   beforeSend: function() {
    $('#cart > button').button('loading');
   },
   complete: function() {
    $('#cart > button').button('reset');
   },
   success: function(json) {
    // Need to set timeout otherwise it wont update the total
    setTimeout(function () {
     $('#cart > button').html('<span id="cart-total"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> ' + json['total'] + '</span>');
    }, 100);

    if (getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/cart' || getURLVar('route') == 'checkout/checkout') {
     location = 'index.php?route=checkout/cart';
    } else {
     $('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
    }
   },
   error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
   }
  });
 }
}

var wishlist = {
 'add': function(product_id) {
  $.ajax({
   url: 'index.php?route=account/wishlist/add',
   type: 'post',
   data: 'product_id=' + product_id,
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(json) {
    $('.alert').remove();

    if (json['redirect']) {
     location = json['redirect'];
    }

    if (json['success']) {
     $('#content').parent().before('<div class="alert alert-success"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> ' + json['success'] + ' <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');
    }

    $('#wishlist-total span').html(json['total']);
    $('#wishlist-total').attr('title', json['total']);

    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
   },
   error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
   }
  });
 },
 'remove': function() {

 }
}

var compare = {
 'add': function(product_id) {
  $.ajax({
   url: 'index.php?route=product/compare/add',
   type: 'post',
   data: 'product_id=' + product_id,
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(json) {
    $('.alert').remove();

    if (json['success']) {
     $('#content').parent().before('<div class="alert alert-success"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> ' + json['success'] + ' <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');

     $('#compare-total').html(json['total']);

     $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
    }
   },
   error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
   }
  });
 },
 'remove': function() {

 }
}

/* Agree to Terms */
$(document).delegate('.agree', 'click', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();

 $('#modal-agree').remove();

 var element = this;

 $.ajax({
  url: $(element).attr('href'),
  type: 'get',
  dataType: 'html',
  success: function(data) {
   html  = '<div id="modal-agree" class="modal">';
   html += '  <div class="modal-dialog">';
   html += '    <div class="modal-content">';
   html += '      <div class="modal-header">';
   html += '        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>';
   html += '        <h4 class="modal-title">' + $(element).text() + '</h4>';
   html += '      </div>';
   html += '      <div class="modal-body">' + data + '</div>';
   html += '    </div';
   html += '  </div>';
   html += '</div>';

   $('body').append(html);

   $('#modal-agree').modal('show');
  }
 });
});

// Autocomplete */
(function($) {
 $.fn.autocomplete = function(option) {
  return this.each(function() {
   this.timer = null;
   this.items = new Array();

   $.extend(this, option);

   $(this).attr('autocomplete', 'off');

   // Focus
   $(this).on('focus', function() {
    this.request();
   });

   // Blur
   $(this).on('blur', function() {
    setTimeout(function(object) {
     object.hide();
    }, 200, this);
   });

   // Keydown
   $(this).on('keydown', function(event) {
    switch(event.keyCode) {
     case 27: // escape
      this.hide();
      break;
     default:
      this.request();
      break;
    }
   });

   // Click
   this.click = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    value = $(event.target).parent().attr('data-value');

    if (value && this.items[value]) {
     this.select(this.items[value]);
    }
   }

   // Show
   this.show = function() {
    var pos = $(this).position();

    $(this).siblings('ul.dropdown-menu').css({
     top: pos.top + $(this).outerHeight(),
     left: pos.left
    });

    $(this).siblings('ul.dropdown-menu').show();
   }

   // Hide
   this.hide = function() {
    $(this).siblings('ul.dropdown-menu').hide();
   }

   // Request
   this.request = function() {
    clearTimeout(this.timer);

    this.timer = setTimeout(function(object) {
     object.source($(object).val(), $.proxy(object.response, object));
    }, 200, this);
   }

   // Response
   this.response = function(json) {
    html = '';

    if (json.length) {
     for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
      this.items[json[i]['value']] = json[i];
     }

     for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
      if (!json[i]['category']) {
       html += '<li data-value="' + json[i]['value'] + '"><a href="#">' + json[i]['label'] + '</a></li>';
      }
     }

     // Get all the ones with a categories
     var category = new Array();

     for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
      if (json[i]['category']) {
       if (!category[json[i]['category']]) {
        category[json[i]['category']] = new Array();
        category[json[i]['category']]['name'] = json[i]['category'];
        category[json[i]['category']]['item'] = new Array();
       }

       category[json[i]['category']]['item'].push(json[i]);
      }
     }

     for (i in category) {
      html += '<li class="dropdown-header">' + category[i]['name'] + '</li>';

      for (j = 0; j < category[i]['item'].length; j++) {
       html += '<li data-value="' + category[i]['item'][j]['value'] + '"><a href="#">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + category[i]['item'][j]['label'] + '</a></li>';
      }
     }
    }

    if (html) {
     this.show();
    } else {
     this.hide();
    }

    $(this).siblings('ul.dropdown-menu').html(html);
   }

   $(this).after('<ul class="dropdown-menu"></ul>');
   $(this).siblings('ul.dropdown-menu').delegate('a', 'click', $.proxy(this.click, this));

  });
 }
})(window.jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function

Судя по разметке [модального окна](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal/), генерируемой в JavaScript, вы используете Bootstrap. Проверьте правильно ли вы подключили **[JS зависимости](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/#js)**, которые включают в себя три файла:

- [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)
- [Popper.js](https://popper.js.org/)
- JavaScript плагины самого Bottstrap.

Для компонента *Tooltips* (всплывающие подсказки) наличие этих библиотек **обязательно**.

Answer (score 1):

Для работы этих подсказок вам нужно [подключить jQuery UI](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jqueryui).

[Документация на сами подсказки.](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)